# Using RXJS to issue two sequential http calls and returning the result of the first one only

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient, rxjs6

I am using RXJS 6 together with Angular 6 HttpClient and I am trying to execute two http calls sequentially.

- I need to **return the result of the first call only**.
- The **first call must be issued before the second**.

I thought of using the tap method as follows:

```
someMethod(items: Item[]): Observable<Item[]> {
   const one = this.http.put<{ items: Item[] }>('urlOne', items);
   const two = this.http.put<void>('urlTwo', items);

   return one.pipe(
     mergeMap((res)=> res.items),
     tap(two)
   );
}
```

Is there a better way? If so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` and just ignore the second result:

```
one.pipe(
  mergeMap((res) => two.pipe(
    mapTo(res)
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot by the way :-)